# Email not sent, but success message shown using django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Everything works fine and I get the Succes message i have set when the email is sent. But its just not sending email to the given address. 
Also I get the following message in terminal when i submit the form, where the local server is running. I believe the 200 message means that the communication is successful.

> "POST /submit/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10141

Given below my views.py, settings.py, forms.py and the template file.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from .forms import SubmitForm
from django.template import Context, loader

from django.core.mail import send_mail,EmailMessage



def submit(request):
  success = False
  success_message = " Thanks!"


  form = SubmitForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        original_title = request.POST.get('original_title')
        english_title = request.POST.get('english_title')

        sent_email = 'receive@email.com'
        message_template = loader.get_template('submit.txt')
        message_context = Context({      'original_title':original_title,'english_title':english_title,
                                    })
        mail = EmailMessage(original_title, english_title, [sent_email])
        mail.send()
        success = True


    return render_to_response('submit.html',
                        {'form' : form,'success': success,'success_message':success_message},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sender@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*****'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Sample < example@gmail.com >
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.contrib.admin import widgets    
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
import os


class SubmitForm(forms.Form):
  title = forms.CharField()
  name = forms.CharField()
```

submit.html

```
                <form method="post" action="{% url 'submit' %}" style="width:75%;margin:auto">{%csrf_token%}

                <legend>Title</legend>
                    <br/>

                    <div class="row">

                        <dl class="field">
                            <dd><label>Title: *</label></dd>

                            <dt class="text">{{ form.name.errors }}
                                             {{ form.original_title }}</dt>

                            <dd class="msg">You filled this out wrong.</dd>
                        </dl>

                        <dl class="field ">
                            <dd><label>English Title: *</label></dd>

                            <dt class="text">{{ form.name.errors }}
                                                {{ form.english_title }}</dt>

                            <dd class="msg">You filled this out wrong.</dd>
                        </dl>


                        <input class="submit three columns" type="submit" value="Register"/>
```

I have added the submit.txt also in proper way. I get the success_message when i click submit but no email sent.

Comment: Are you running a mail server?  What do your mail logs say?  The ""POST /submit/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10141" message just means the web server got the HTTP post request to the /submit/ url, and returned a 200 status.

Comment: what is `mail.send()` ? A custom method? AFAIk, it is `mail.send_mail()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail

Comment: Ah, I see you are trying to send to gmail.  Never mind then ...   You can always try running your own mail server to debug the problem.  Or sniff your outgoing connection to see if the mail is sent.

Comment: what is mail log? how can i check that?

Comment: i used mail.send() in other project and its working good. Mail is not sent and i tried with my own mail server also. Thats not the problem

Comment: the mail log is what the mail daemon writes when it sends or receives an email.  If you use gmail as your mail server, you won't be able to check the mail log ... well I shouldn't say that, I don't use gmail and I don't know if they make logs available.  But I'd be surprised if they did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize an `EmailMessage`, the third argument is the from address. You appear to have a list containing the receiver's address instead.

Make sure you create your message in the same way [as the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects):

```
email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'Body goes here', 'from@example.com',
            ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'], ['bcc@example.com'],
            headers = {'Reply-To': 'another@example.com'})
```

Comment: But actualy what about my message_context? i want the request’s POST data to be included as the 'Body goes here' in the 'message_template' format.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want your body to be. In your question, you load a template, create a context, but you don't do anything with those variables. You can replace 'Body goes here' with whatever you want. Maybe you want to render the template with your context then use that as the body?

Comment: yes. I have a long form with a lot fields. I want to bring the data from form as the body of the email in the given submit.txt template.

Comment: In case you don't know, you can use [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut) to render your template with the context, then use that as the body.